# determining the type of placeholder at runtime c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, methods

```
public void compare<T>(T someobject)
{
  .....
  .....
}
```

Now i want to determine the type of `T` at runtime and do different operation based upon that. I have tried using the `typeof` but to no avail.

Comment: `typeof(T)` should indeed work. What exactly have you tried with `typeof`?

Comment: `typeof(T)` will give you the compile-time type used when invoking the method not the actual type of `someObject`. What about `GetType()`?

Comment: `if (typeof(T).Equals(int))
            {

            }`

Comment: @WinCoder if you call `compare((object)1)` do you want `System.Object` or `System.Int32`? `typeof(T)` will give you the former, while `someObject.GetType()` the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typeof should work fine in runtime.

```
    public void compare<T>(T someobject)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(something else))
        {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i do `typeof(T)==int` it says `invalid expression term int`

Comment: see my edit, stackoverflow answer box needs intellisense, LOL

Answer (score 2):

`is` can be used to check the parameter type

```
if (someobject is SomeType)//...
```

Or, alternatively...

```
        Type constructedType = typeof(T);
        if (constructedType == typeof(SomeType))//...
```

Comment: `is` wont work with `T` as `T` is a `Typedecriptor` not a `Type`

Comment: Oh, my bad, I see your checking against `someobject` not the `T` :), `is` will work in this secenario :)

Answer (score 1):

Can try

```
typeof(T) == typeof(desiredType)
```

For example:

```
typeof(T) == typeof(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (someobj.GetType() == typeof(ClassA)) { /* do opertion */},
```